# Delegate getting nil while using protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I want to call a method `FromFilter:` located in **ProductListViewController** from other class **FilterViewController**,

when i try to call a method i am getting nil value of delegate,

Here is my code snippet:

**ProductListViewController.h**

```
@protocol FirstControllerDelegate<NSObject>
@required
-(void)FromFilter:(NSString *)StrApi;

@end

@interface ProductListViewController : UIViewController<FirstControllerDelegate>{
   ....
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FirstControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

**ProductListViewController.m**

```
-(void)FromFilter:(NSString *)StrApi{
    NSLog(@"------- this is not getting called ---------");
}
```

**FilterViewController.h**

```
@interface FilterViewController : UIViewController{
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FirstControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

**FilterViewController.m**

```
    - (IBAction)ApplyClicked:(id)sender {

    // -----  Here my _delegate is nil ------

    if (_delegate == nil) {
        [_delegate FromFilter:@"fuyds"];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Please help, where i am doing mistake?**

Comment: you need to assign delegate property, maybe you forgot this?

Comment: And why do you have delegate property in ProductListViewController? It seems that ProductListViewController should be a delegate of FilterViewController. So you need to assign your ProductListViewController instance to a property of FilterViewController

Comment: i removed delegate property from ProductListViewController, still not working

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko where should i assign delegate property?

Comment: Where do you set the delegate ? Also you have if(_delegate == nil) ? Don't you mean != nil?

Comment: Please name the method (and the parameters) starting with a lowercase: `-(void)FromFilter:(NSString *)StrApi`=> `-(void)fromFilter:(NSString *)strApi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be you didn't assign the delegate property of "FilterViewController".

whenever you create FilterViewController

Example :

```
FilterViewController *filterViewController = [[FilterViewController alloc]init];

filterViewController.delegate  = self;//important
```

If you are presenting FilterViewController from ProductListViewController then you should assign the delegate as self

Comment: where you create FilterViewController? there after creating the filterViewController , put this filterViewController.delegate  = self;//important

Comment: I am not creating object of FilterViewController any where

Comment: FilterViewController *filterViewController = [[FilterViewController alloc]init]; is an example. like this you would create it from storyboard or somewhere in ProductListViewController. check it out

Comment: I am not using storyboard in my project, can u please tell me what should i write and where means in which method of ProductListViewController class?

Comment: if you didn't create the FilterViewController either from code or storyboard then there is no possible to show that view to the user. i hope you are doing it somewhere.search your project for "FilterViewController alloc". if you didn't create it then how did u click the "ApplyClick"

Comment: Yes dude u r write i forgot to write filterViewController.delegate  = self;

Answer (score 0):

```
if (_delegate == nil) {
        [_delegate FromFilter:@"fuyds"];
    }
```

Of course your `FromFilter` method isn't called. Your code calls this method of `_delegate` object only if `_delegate` is nil. Essentially, your code is this:

```
[nil FromFilter];
```

In Objective C you can send messages to `nil`, they simply do nothing and return 0 (nil, NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the code to:

```
- (IBAction)ApplyClicked:(id)sender {

// -----  Here my _delegate is nil ------

if (_delegate != nil) { // != NOT == --> you want to enter the if clause if the delegate is NOT nil
    [_delegate FromFilter:@"fuyds"];
}

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: A short version would be: `if (_delegate) [_delegate FromFilter:@"fuyds"];`